# Java Generic Enumerator for classes

Tags: java, generics, enums

I want to create an enumerator with classes to get these classes in further code but I can't.
I'll explain on example what I want to do:

```
public enum SomeEnumeratorForClasses {
  FIRST_CLASS( "Name 1", FirstClass.class ),
  SECOND_CLASS( "Name 2", SecondClass.class );

  private String name;
  private Class<T> response;

  SomeEnumeratorForClasses ( String name, Class<T> clazz ) {...}

  public Class<T> getResponse() {
    return response;
  }
}
```

For example each class first/second has some fields/method example:

```
getDescription()
```

And finally in other class I want something like that:

```
SomeEnumeratorForClasses.FIRST_CLASS.getResponse().getDescription();
```

But I can't do it. Each class inherit from other base class Zero.class example:

```
FirstClass extends Zero
SecondClass extends Zero
```

I try do this also instead

```
private Class<T> response;
```

use this:

```
private Class<? extends Zero> response;
```

But still doesn't work.

Method getDescription is not static, is a public String for example:

```
class FirstClass {
  public String getDescription() {
    return "Text";
  }
}
```

Some methods like getDesciptions are abstract in Zero class.
How can I do it?

Comment: It is not static method, is public String method.

Comment: Is your `getDescription` declared in `Zero` class? Is it only method you want to access via this enum?

Comment: If it is not static then to invoke it you need *instance* on which it will be invoked (just like getter needs instance from which it will read value it needs to return), not class literal.

Comment: If `getResponse()` returns a `Class` then you will not be able to invoke any custom methods on it (like `getDescription()`) - those are instance methods of that class, you need to have an object, not a `Class`.

Comment: Adam Michalik: so getResponse() should return instance of this class?

Comment: Thanks for answers I did it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that each class shares a constructor signature (preferably a public no-args version), you can write a function that instantiates them.

```
public class ObjectUtils {
    private ObjectUtils(){}

    public static <T> T init(Class<T> clazz, Object... args) {
        try {

            return (T) Arrays.stream(clazz.getConstructors())
                    .filter(construct -> Objects.equals(args.length, construct.getParameterCount()))
                    .filter(construct -> IntStream.range(0, construct.getParameterTypes().length)
                            .allMatch(val -> construct.getParameterTypes()[val].isAssignableFrom(args[val].getClass())))
                    .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new InstantiationException("Could not find compatible constructor."))
                    .newInstance(args);

        } catch (InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not instantiate class for provided arguments.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your enum could look like:

```
public enum SomeEnumeratorForClasses {
  FIRST_CLASS( "Name 1", FirstClass.class ),
  SECOND_CLASS( "Name 2", SecondClass.class );

  private String name;
  private Class<? extends Zero> responseClass;

  SomeEnumeratorForClasses ( String name, Class<? extends Zero> responseClass ) {
       this.name = name;
       this.responseClass = responseClass;
  }

  public <T extends Zero> T getResponse() {
    return ObjectUtils.init(responseClass);
  }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
SomeEnumeratorForClasses.FIRST_CLASS.getResponse().getDescription();
```